# how to check that MS Word is running using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, process

we have an application that runs MS Word (hidden) to print documents.

If one of the printers has a problem, then Word hangs while waiting for the spooler to return the 'queued' message.

We have found that if we make Word visible (by using VBA in Excel with `GetObject` and `oWordApp.visible=true` for example) then the process continues printing the other documents with no problem.

We would like to make this more automatic by having a VBScript check for Word in running processes, if it finds it, make it visible, wait for a few seconds, hide it, and quit...

But I have a problem that the VBScript `GetObject` function instantiates Word if it's not already running.

how should I check that word is running using VBScript without creating an instance of it?

here is the code I have in my VBScript file:

```
dim oWord, WScriptShell

set oWord = getobject("", "Word.Application")
set WScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

if isobject(oWord)  then 'and oWord.Documents.count>0
    wscript.echo("Word is running")
    oWord.visible=true
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    oWord.visible=false
else
    wscript.echo("Word not running")
end if
```

so what should I use to check if word is running without creating an instance of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change `GetObject("", "Word.Application")` to `GetObject(, "Word.Application")` and it doesn't start an instance.
But this throws an error if Word is *not* running, so you can use it like this:

```
msgbox wordIsRunning

function wordIsRunning
    dim wdApp
    on error resume next
    set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wordIsRunning = (err.Number = 0)
    set wdApp = nothing
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

> Word hangs

check "DisplayAlerts" property. allowed only if property "Visible" set to "True".

> tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq winword.exe"

will show you, does m$word running or not

Comment: so should I include `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq winword.exe"` in my VBScript?

Comment: no, that is windows shell command/program. you could run it by using WScript.Shell